# Alternative(To Google Maps) Open Source Map API that provides a database of nodes and Arcs on roads

Tags: android, api, google-maps, geolocation, maps

I need a Map API for Android that can provide me with indexed nodes and indices that make up the road network. The main idea is to determine if two GPS devices are on the same road. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Map API by itself will not have that information. Anyway, you can get it from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) freely. You can download it from [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data).

I don't understand from your question if you intend on displaying the results on a map. If so, and you want a nice and free map API, I would suggest [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/). It's not as mature as the likes of [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) but, as you've tagged this post with "android", Leaflet just kicks ass in the mobile department.

Comment: Thank you. What i need is to render my maps on an android application. I have maps that have GPS coordinated of nodes and the arcs between them that form the road network. I need my application to detect that two devices are on the same road

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap is definitely a good source of data for this kind of project. Unlike google maps, it gives developers access to the underlying vector data of a map (fully open). This allows interesting new use cases which simply are not possible with google maps, and something involving geometric calculations like this would definitely fit into that category. You either need OpenStreetMap or some other source of "vector" map data, and beyond OpenStreetMap this can be expensive.

Unfortunately that's not the full answer to your question. You still have a lot of work to do to *use* the data in the way you intend. You need to calculate the proximity of two points (GPS readings from two devices?) to nearby roads, and figure out which road the point lies closest to. It's the kind of powerful geo calculation you might do using a GIS package such as QGIS or a functions of a geo-aware database system PostGIS.

But that's not the answer to your question, because you need to do these calculations on device. I'm not aware of an off-the-shelf library to do this on android. I think you would have to roll your own.

But another challenge is to get the vector data onto the device in a suitable format in the first place, and this is the first thing to solve. You'd want the vector data either as a large download for a whole country, or perhaps a smaller area, perhaps with an on-the-fly download feature within this app. Whole countries are not infeasible when working with maps in vector form (ever tried the awesome [MayDroyd](http://www.mapdroyd.com/) app?), but require some compact formatting. Happily some of these problems are starting to be solved in open source off-the-shelf libraries. You could try to build on top of [MapsForge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) for example.

So then you're back to the challenge of writing on-device code to poke around in this data and do the calculations you want to do. I suppose it could be rather good if projects like MapsForge included generic PostGIS style geo-functions to make this easier. Something to ask the mapsforge developers about perhaps.

Comment: Dear Harry, you can use spatialite-android library to port Spatialite into android devices. It has most of the features that PostGIS provides in desktop environment.